# How can I bring back MBProgressHUDs that went away when a UIAlertView was shown?

Tags: ios, uialertview, mbprogresshud

My app shows an MBProgressHUD added to the main window while it fetches data from the server.  If it needs to login, it shows a UIAlertView to prompt the user for username & password.  When the UIAlertView shows, the MBProgressHUD hides - this isn't due to anything in my code, but it is behaviour that I want.  However, when the UIAlertView goes away, I want the HUD to come back.  I can get them by calling `[MBProgressHUD allHUDsForView:window]`, but their superview is now `nil` and calling `-[show:]` has no effect.

How can I bring back MBProgressHUDs that went away when a UIAlertView was shown?

Comment: please post the code where you init and add it to the window. And where you are sending the `show:` message.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer for your exact problem but an alternative way to solve your problem ,

I would try to control progress hud by myself knowing that I am the one who calls the uilaertview and  dissmises it. SO why not to use two huds?

```
// Add when your fetch method is called
        MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        hud.labelText = @"Loading...";


//in your alertview method
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:@"Message"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    //dissmiss progress hud before alertview is shown
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

    [alert show];

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"OK"])
    {
        NSLog(@"OK button is clicked on alertview");

         //show another hud
         MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        hud.labelText = @"Loading...";

    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately due to the way my code is stuctured this is impossible.  I'll post more code when I'm in less of a hurry.  Thanks anyway.